# jQuery DataTables length update problem

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dynamic data table defined.

```
ListLone_datatable = jQuery('#my_table').dataTable(
    {
        'bFilter': false,
        'bPaginate': true,
        'iDisplayLength': 5,
        'bLengthChange': false,
        'bSort': true,
        'bInfo': true,
        'bAutoWidth': false,
        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
        'oLanguage': 
        {
            'oPaginate': 
            {
                'sPrevious': '&laquo;',
                'sNext': '&raquo;'
            }
        },
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sDom': '<"dataTables_top"pi>lftpir',
        'bDestroy': true,
        'sAjaxSource': ListLone_datasource_url + ListLone_filter,
        'aoColumns': 
            [
                {
                    'fnRender': 
                        function(row_data) 
                        { return _icon_html(row_data.aData[8], 'property_new.gif') },
                    'bSortable': false
                },
                {
                    'fnRender': 
                        function(row_data) 
                        { return _icon_html(row_data.aData[9], 'property_featured.png') }, 
                    'bSortable': false
                },
                {
                    'fnRender': 
                        function(row_data) 
                        { 
                        console.log('rowdata', row_data);
                            var control_div =
                                '<div class="row-actions">';

                            control_div += 
                                '<span><a href="' + row_data.aData[7] + 
                                '" target="_blank">View</a> | </span>';
                            control_div += 
                                '<span><a href="admin.php?page=_properties&id=' + 
                                row_data.aData[10] + '">Edit</a> | </span>';
                            control_div += 
                                '<span><a href="admin.php?page=_properties&id=' + 
                                row_data.aData[10] +'" class="pl_listing_delete">Delete</a> | </span>';

                            if (typeof(Admin_properties_item_menu) != 'undefined')
                            {
                                var addon_data = Admin_properties_item_menu(row_data.aData);
                                control_div += addon_data;
                            }

                            control_div += 
                                '<span>' +
                                _flag_html(row_data.aData[10], row_data.aData[8], 
                                    'is_new', 'New', 0, 'property_new.gif') +
                                ' | </span>';
                            control_div += 
                                '<span>' +
                                _flag_html(row_data.aData[10], row_data.aData[9], 
                                    'is_featured', 'Featured', 1, 
                                    'property_featured.png') +
                                '</span>';

                            control_div += '</div>';

                            excerpt_div = '';
                            if (!ListLone_is_mode_list)
                                excerpt_div = '<div>' + row_data.aData[11] + '</div>';

                            return row_data.aData[2] + excerpt_div + control_div;
                        }
                },
                {'fnRender': function(row_data) { return row_data.aData[3] }},
                {'fnRender': function(row_data) { return row_data.aData[4] }},
                {'fnRender': function(row_data) { return row_data.aData[5] }},
                {'fnRender': function(row_data) { return row_data.aData[6] }},
                {'fnRender': function(row_data) { return _featured_small_image(row_data.aData[12]) }},
                {'bVisible': false},
                {'bVisible': false},
                {'bVisible': false},
                {'bVisible': false},
                {'bVisible': false}
            ]
    });
```

The problem is that the pagination information does not get updated when items are deleted from the datasource.

I did test with:

```
console.log(ListLone_datatable.fnGetData());
```

and everything seems to be in order. The updated list of items is correct. The correct items are displayed in the table, just not the pagination information. For example if a had 6 items displayed 5 per page, after I delete one item, the table displays two pages and the second page empty and the text reads "Showing 1 to 5 of 6 entries". (Of course after reload). It seems to retain the initial state of the table / pagination. If switch to another new pagination setting (like 6 per page), it seems to update its initial state to a correct one, but still doesn't work.

The only way kinda force to update its info is to perform a column sort. That however, is lost on reload. What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the jQuery('#my_table').dataTable() function again to update the table.  You may need to pass in custom params, to retain any changes or dynamic adds/edits have been made to the table data.

Comment: The weird thing is that the problem seems to persist even when the page is refreshed, that is to say when table is initialized again with the new data. The received data is modified, and the table content is modified, but the table stats (pagination and info) are the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables has a function call fnDraw() which redraws the table for you once you have deleted the data it depends on.

```
$('#my_table').fnDraw()
```

Comment: As I understand it, that only reloads the table. My problems seems to persist even when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

try forcing `"bStateSave": false`